# How to index objects in For loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to index "model" object so that I can choose the model with best fit right after. The result I would like to see is: model[i,j]. If I try to index it says:
"Error in model[i, j] <- glm(newcol ~ ., data = mod_data[c(mod_tab_new)],:incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"

here is the code:

```
rm(list = ls())

mod_data <- NULL
mod_data$Sex <- sample(0:1, size = 1000, replace = T)
mod_data$Age <- sample(18:99, size = 1000, replace = T)
mod_data <- data.frame(mod_data)

mod_data$newcol <- sample(0:1, size = nrow(mod_data), replace = T)

mod_headers <- names(mod_data[1:ncol(mod_data)-1])

f <- function(mod_headers){
  for(i in 1:length(mod_headers)){
    tab <- combn(mod_headers,i)
    for(j in 1:ncol(tab)){
      tab_new <- c(tab[,j])
      mod_tab_new <- c(tab_new, "newcol")
      model[i,j] <- glm(newcol ~., data=mod_data[c(mod_tab_new)], family = binomial(link = "logit"))
    }
  }
}

f(mod_headers)
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: One needs to predefine the matrix's shape prior to the assignment.  Add something like: `model<-matrix(nrow=length(mod_headers), ncol=ncol(tab))` prior to the for loops.  Note if the value of `tab` needs to set to the maximum expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
f <- function(mod_headers){

model <- list()


for(i in 1:length(mod_headers)){
   tab <- combn(mod_headers,i)
   model[[i]] <- list()

      for(j in 1:ncol(tab)){

       tab_new <- c(tab[,j])
       mod_tab_new <- c(tab_new, "newcol")
       model[[i]][[j]] <- glm(newcol ~., data=mod_data[c(mod_tab_new)], family = binomial(link = "logit"))
   }
  }

model
}
```

Always before a `for`loop where you intend to fill a data structure with values you have to define the data structure first. In this case I made a list and filled it with the `glm` objects.